# GNU Radio io_signature

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I'm getting into GNU Radio and after I created a new block, in the main class I have a peace of code like this :

```
square_ff_impl::square_ff_impl()
  : gr::block("square_ff",
              gr::io_signature::make(<+IMIN+>, <+IMAX+>, sizeof (<+ITYPE+>)), // input signature
              gr::io_signature::make(<+OMIN+>, <+OMAX+>, sizeof (<+OTYPE+>))) // output signature
{
    // empty constructor
}
```

I don't really know exactly what to put in MIN and MAX (even after reading the doc).

Can you give me some examples please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IMIN - minimum number of acceptable input ports
IMAX - maximum number of acceptable input ports
OMIN - minimum number of acceptable output ports
OMAX - maximum number of acceptable output ports
```

The documentation talks about it a bit in the IOSignatures portion of the [BlocksCodingGuide](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/BlocksCodingGuide):

> - The first two parameters are min and max number of ports, this allows
>     blocks to have a selectable number of ports at runtime.

A value of -1 means "unlimited".

As an example of a source block, take a look at the IO signature of the [null source](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-blocks/lib/null_source_impl.cc#L43) block, which takes no input:

```
null_source_impl::null_source_impl (size_t sizeof_stream_item)
  : sync_block("null_source",
                  io_signature::make(0, 0, 0),
                  io_signature::make(1, -1, sizeof_stream_item))
{
}
```

For a sink, check out [null sink](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-blocks/lib/null_sink_impl.cc#L42), which has no output:

```
null_sink_impl::null_sink_impl(size_t sizeof_stream_item)
  : sync_block("null_sink",
               io_signature::make(1, -1, sizeof_stream_item),
               io_signature::make(0, 0, 0))
{
}
```

And a simple processing blocks, [add_ff](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-blocks/lib/add_ff_impl.cc#L40), which takes unlimited input and produces exactly 1 output stream:

```
add_ff_impl::add_ff_impl(size_t vlen)
  : sync_block("add_ff",
          io_signature::make (1, -1, sizeof(float)*vlen),
          io_signature::make (1,  1, sizeof(float)*vlen)),
d_vlen(vlen)
{
...
```

Comment: I think I get it know : if this i a source OMIN = 1 , OMAX = -1 (theoretically) and IMIN and IMAX = 0 both right ?

Comment: @Kruncho, exactly. Added more details and examples from existing blocks to the answer.

Comment: @Kruncho: most people start with sources that have *exactly* 1 output port, so OMIN=1=OMAX.

Comment: @djanderson The "Blocks coding guide" link is broken: could you updated it?

Comment: @djanderson Thanks for the speedy response!